# URL '/help/library/<package>/r/html/00Index.html' not found when using `devtools::load_all()`

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I am using `devtools::load_all` as a workflow to iteratively make a package. However, I cannot seem to be able to view the package documentation using `?` or `help(package=package_name)` until I install the package. The error I get is:

No documentation for ‘function’ in specified packages and libraries

and

URL '/help/library//r/html/00Index.html'

any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `devtools::document()`? I don't believe `load_all` will build the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the help(package=package_name) do nothing than open (in case of Windows) this file for you:

C:\Users\YourName\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\package_name\html\00Index.html

`devtools::load_all` make your latest functions available to you for testing without installing the package (i.e. the html file was not updated, and masked because it was belonged to the old version of your own package). To view your latest documentation (i.e. make a new version html), you can `devtools::document()` and check your package working directory `\man\Functions_name.rd`, **OR**, `devtools::install()` and `help(package=package_name)`

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting r session solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When creating an R package using devtools, RStudio, and roxygen2, I encountered an issue where the '00index.html' and the "help" folder page was missing during development. Despite efforts like restarting RStudio and reinstalling R, the issue persisted. However, after generating the source package and installing it on another machine, the full documentation, including the index page, was correctly displayed. This suggests that the absence of the index page during development may not be a concern for the final package documentation.